# WP8, DoubleAnimation - "Cannot resolve TargetName" exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, storyboard

I want to create marquee effect in WP8 application.
To accomplish this I placed **StackPanel** inside **ScrollViewer** and I'm trying to use **DoubleAnimation** on  **TranslateTransform.X** property.

Code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Scroll" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Storyboard.TargetName="transform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:5" />
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    ...
    <ScrollViewer Height="80" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

            <Image Source="/Assets/logo1.png"></Image>
            <Image Source="/Assets/logo2.png"></Image>
            <Image Source="/Assets/logo3.png"></Image>
            <Image Source="/Assets/logo4.png"></Image>
            <Image Source="/Assets/logo5.png"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Unfortunately when calling **Scroll.Begin()** from code-behind in page **Loaded** event handler I'm getting exception: **System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve TargetName transform**.

What I'am doing wrong? 
Animation runs when I place StackPanel directly in LayoutRoot but not when it's child of ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the exception is explanatory. Like you apply storyboard on some UI element but there is no element named "transform" in your xaml to which this storyboard will be going to be applied.

so this property `Storyboard.TargetName` should be name of the UI element that has to be transformed.

In your case if you have to simply give your `StackPanel` a name say `MyStackPanel` and then put this name in place of `transform` in your storyboard code.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="MyStackPanel">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
...
```

You storyboard should be changedin this way..

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Scroll" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Storyboard.TargetName="MyStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:5" />
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

**Important** :-It would be much better if you just use Blend for making a simple animation and then see how the animation code generated in the page Xaml. You will got all of your answers :)

Comment: Your code didn't work but thank you for pointing that I can use Blend to create animation. It generated working code: `Storyboard.TargetName="MyStackPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"`. Additionaly I have to wrap StackPanel inside Grid control

Comment: I have just written that from top of my head :) @gumis pls edit my ans with your working code..so that it will work for others :)